# flatpak and kde (Kexi) problem: app/org.kde.kexi/i386/master not installed

Tags: kde

I tried to install the stable version of Kexi.

(I am on Ubuntu 16.04) When I try to run kexi I get a non installed:

```
pp@acerlaptop:~$ flatpak --filesystem=$HOME run org.kde.kexi
error: app/org.kde.kexi/i386/master not installed
pp@acerlaptop:~$ flatpak list
```

On the other hand I see Kexi is installed :

```
pp@acerlaptop:~$ apt-cache policy kexi
kexi: Installed: 1:2.9.7-0ubuntu12 Candidate: 1:2.9.7-0ubuntu12 Version table: *** 1:2.9.7-0ubuntu12 500
    500 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Somebody can help?

Comment: `apt` and `apt-cache` can see only debs. Apt has never heard of Flatpacks (nor Snaps, nor App Images, etc), and has no idea if any non-deb is installed. If apt says that kexi is installed, it means the kexi deb is installed.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. I could start kexi in GUI.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and elaborate on that as otherwise your question (**not your answer**) will be closed as *cannot be reproduced*...